# I need to get my Arrays to Display their information in a textbox but it's not working (more details below)

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

```
#pragma once

namespace StudentDataSearch {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnSearch;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  Course_ID1;
    protected: 

    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtTargetID;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox^  groupBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtSeats;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  Seats;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtID;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  Course_ID;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtName;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  Course_Names2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->btnSearch = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->Course_ID1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->txtTargetID = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->groupBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox());
            this->txtSeats = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->Seats = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->txtID = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->Course_ID = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->txtName = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->Course_Names2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->groupBox1->SuspendLayout();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnSearch
            // 
            this->btnSearch->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
            this->btnSearch->Name = L"btnSearch";
            this->btnSearch->Size = System::Drawing::Size(144, 39);
            this->btnSearch->TabIndex = 0;
            this->btnSearch->Text = L"Search by Course ID";
            this->btnSearch->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btnSearch->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnSearch_Click);
            // 
            // Course_ID1
            // 
            this->Course_ID1->AutoSize = true;
            this->Course_ID1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(317, 28);
            this->Course_ID1->Name = L"Course_ID1";
            this->Course_ID1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(54, 13);
            this->Course_ID1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->Course_ID1->Text = L"Course ID";
            // 
            // txtTargetID
            // 
            this->txtTargetID->Location = System::Drawing::Point(377, 25);
            this->txtTargetID->Name = L"txtTargetID";
            this->txtTargetID->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->txtTargetID->TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // groupBox1
            // 
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->txtSeats);
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->Seats);
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->txtID);
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->Course_ID);
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->txtName);
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->Course_Names2);
            this->groupBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 145);
            this->groupBox1->Name = L"groupBox1";
            this->groupBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(465, 140);
            this->groupBox1->TabIndex = 3;
            this->groupBox1->TabStop = false;
            this->groupBox1->Text = L"Search Results";
            // 
            // txtSeats
            // 
            this->txtSeats->Location = System::Drawing::Point(301, 81);
            this->txtSeats->Name = L"txtSeats";
            this->txtSeats->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->txtSeats->TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // Seats
            // 
            this->Seats->AutoSize = true;
            this->Seats->Location = System::Drawing::Point(298, 65);
            this->Seats->Name = L"Seats";
            this->Seats->Size = System::Drawing::Size(34, 13);
            this->Seats->TabIndex = 4;
            this->Seats->Text = L"Seats";
            // 
            // txtID
            // 
            this->txtID->Location = System::Drawing::Point(204, 81);
            this->txtID->Name = L"txtID";
            this->txtID->Size = System::Drawing::Size(91, 20);
            this->txtID->TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // Course_ID
            // 
            this->Course_ID->AutoSize = true;
            this->Course_ID->Location = System::Drawing::Point(206, 65);
            this->Course_ID->Name = L"Course_ID";
            this->Course_ID->Size = System::Drawing::Size(54, 13);
            this->Course_ID->TabIndex = 2;
            this->Course_ID->Text = L"Course ID";
            // 
            // txtName
            // 
            this->txtName->Location = System::Drawing::Point(25, 81);
            this->txtName->Name = L"txtName";
            this->txtName->Size = System::Drawing::Size(173, 20);
            this->txtName->TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // Course_Names2
            // 
            this->Course_Names2->AutoSize = true;
            this->Course_Names2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(22, 65);
            this->Course_Names2->Name = L"Course_Names2";
            this->Course_Names2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(71, 13);
            this->Course_Names2->TabIndex = 0;
            this->Course_Names2->Text = L"Course Name";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 57);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(144, 39);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 4;
            this->button1->Text = L"Search by Course Name";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(519, 297);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->groupBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txtTargetID);
            this->Controls->Add(this->Course_ID1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnSearch);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Student Data Search";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
            this->groupBox1->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->groupBox1->PerformLayout();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
        private: array<String^>^ CourseArr;
        private: array<String^>^ CourseID;
        private: array<Int32^>^ SeatsArr;
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 // Course Names
                 CourseArr = gcnew array<String^>(9);
                 CourseArr->SetValue("Computer Sci 1511", 0);
                 CourseArr->SetValue("Computer Sci 1521", 1);
                 CourseArr->SetValue("Composition 1120", 2);
                 CourseArr->SetValue("Math 1296", 3);
                 CourseArr->SetValue("Physics 1120", 4);
                 CourseArr->SetValue("Biology 1100", 5);
                 CourseArr->SetValue("Chemistry 1100", 6);
                 CourseArr->SetValue("Anthropology 1210", 7);
                 CourseArr->SetValue("Economics 1000", 8);

                 // Course ID
                 CourseID = gcnew array<String^>(9);
                 CourseID->SetValue("123", 0);
                 CourseID->SetValue("124", 1);
                 CourseID->SetValue("135", 2);
                 CourseID->SetValue("145", 3);
                 CourseID->SetValue("146", 4);
                 CourseID->SetValue("149", 5);
                 CourseID->SetValue("155", 6);
                 CourseID->SetValue("162", 7);
                 CourseID->SetValue("175", 8);

                 //Seats Avaliable
                 SeatsArr->SetValue("0", 0);
                 SeatsArr->SetValue("25", 1);
                 SeatsArr->SetValue("14", 2);
                 SeatsArr->SetValue("5", 3);
                 SeatsArr->SetValue("0", 4);
                 SeatsArr->SetValue("20", 5);
                 SeatsArr->SetValue("17", 6);
                 SeatsArr->SetValue("0", 7);
                 SeatsArr->SetValue("12", 8);

             }




private: System::Void btnSearch_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
```

Error below here ----------------------------------------------

I have set up a few array to gather information and so far I have set values to my 3 arrays and set up a for loop to run through the arrays and pick out the desired information based on what is put into my textbox Course ID but it's not printing anything and I'm not sure why I thought by assigning the arrays to variables and then putting the variables in the text box that would work and at this point I am beyond lost and I know my explanation isn't necessarily helpful but all help is appreciated

```
             int course;
             int id;
             int seats;
             for (int i = 0; i < course; i++)
             {
                 txtName->Text = CourseArr[i]->ToString();
                 txtID->Text =CourseID[i]->ToString(); 
                 txtSeats->Text = SeatsArr[i]->ToString();

                 course = CourseArr[i]->ToString();
                 id = CourseID[i]->ToString();
                 seats = SeatsArr[i]->ToString();

             }


         }
};
}
```

Comment: Pay attention to the warnings that the compiler generates when it compiles your code.  It tells you what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is trying to put strings in an array of integers. Also, why did you declare an array of *boxed* integers?

And why use `SetValue` instead of indexing the array normally?

Comment: I'm simply following what the book tells me and going off that to write my code